# Can I retrieve project files from production using the sf CLI?

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, files, production, cli, retrieve

When I run `sf project retrieve start` on a **production** Org, it says:

```
Error (1): This command can only be used on orgs that have source tracking enabled, such as sandboxes and scratch orgs
```

Is there a way to retrieve all project files locally from a production environment? Is this possible using the Salesforce CLI?

On my sandbox this solve the issue, but I would like to do the same on production if possible in any way.

Comment: Not something I've tried. Depending how the updated CLI behaves, you might be able to use the deprecated (legacy) [`sfdx force:source:retrieve`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_retrieve) command. This didn't require source tracking. Interestingly, that documentation suggests `sf project retrieve start` should automatically work against an org without source tracking enabled...

Comment: Always helpful to mention what the version is for things that you're using (and always a first step to check to see if there are updates).

Comment: @PhilW your solution seems to work. Is there a way to keep doing this in future versions as this method is deprectated?

Comment: Honestly not sure, but the point is it should be able to work with the new command. Perhaps you should consider raising a bug in the [CLI bug tracker](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues)?

Comment: @PhilW Posted an issue on Github: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2693

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As answered on the GitHub issue I posted for this**

> sf project retrieve start (with no flags) will try to retrieve the
> changes, and requires source tracking.

**Possible options**

> sf project retrieve start --source-dir [wherever your project files
> are
>
> or sf project retrieve start --metadata x to get all the metadata of
> one or more types if you know what you want.

**Source**

https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2693#issuecomment-1929770246